# Adding <li> to nl2br

Tags: php, html

```
<p><?php echo nl2br($course->getSubjects())?></p>
```

Is it possible to add an `<li>` to every new line?

Comment: Sorry you can't do it with nl2br because it Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string. I suggest you to make an array.

Comment: Not directly but think of a solution using `str_replace`

Comment: Explode the value using new line and iterate over it

Answer (score 0):

You can imlement it with `str_replace` like the following example:

```
$aaa = 'ghjh sdf \n dfg dfg \n jhdsfjk';
$list= str_replace('\n','</li><li>',$aa);

print_r('<li>'.$list);
```

If `$course->getSubjects()` contains value then You can change your code to:

```
$list= str_replace('\n','</li><li>',$course->getSubjects());

print_r('<li>'.$list);
```